# Is there a single word that can be defined as "the ability to provide (fiscally)"

Tags: single-word-requests

I thought 'providence' might work, but it doesn't seem to quite fit the bill. The sentence I'm trying to complete is:

"Needs are those things that preserve life, health, home, and [word-goes-here]."

Comment: To provide fiscally, you need a job, so maybe: *Needs are those things that preserve life, health, home, and employment.* Or "ability to provide" is a common enough phrase (42 million hits on Google): *Needs are those things that preserve life, health, home, and the ability to provide.*

Comment: Employment is not necessarily needed to be able to provide fiscally. E.g., the very wealthy that live off investment interest. Maintaining that interest-bearing principle would be just as much a need to them as a job would be to us pleebs. I'm definitely looking to define the ability itself - not the specific means that provide it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could go with something like "Needs are those things that preserve life, health, home and

- financial stability
- solvency
- the ability to provide (as @JLG said)

Comment: I like 'solvency'.  That's, I think, the closest to what I'm looking for.

Comment: @FelixT.Katt FYI, [solvency](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/solvent) is defined as _having assets in excess of liabilities; **able to pay one’s debts**_. It is also financial jargon that will very likely not be understood by the layman.

Comment: @coleopterist - it's pretty standard English here. Definitely not technical jargon :-)

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't the cliché go something along the lines of *health, wealth and happiness*? My suggestions would be:

- wealth
- [wherewithal](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/wherewithal)
- income
- means
- resources